# Function. ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, geolocation

I have a function `geolocate(country)`

```
def geolocate(country):
    try:
        # Geolocate the center of the country
        loc = geolocator.geocode(country)
        # And return latitude and longitude
        return (loc.latitude, loc.longitude)
    except:
        # Return missing value
        return np.nan
```

The function works well with separate values:

```
geolocate("UA")
>> (49.4871968, 31.2718321)
```

But with a pandas dataframe `pmap` it returns an Error:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

The pmap looks like follow:

```
            name  quality_of_life_index  country continent
0    Afghanistan                    NaN       AF        AS
1  Aland Islands                    NaN  Unknown   Unknown
2        Albania              98.710473       AL        EU
3       Alderney                    NaN  Unknown   Unknown
4        Algeria              98.686111       DZ        AF
```

I tried this:

```
pmap[['latitude', 'longitude']] = [geolocate(x) for x in pmap['country']]
```

Comment: I think you should return `np.nan, np.nan` in the `except` block.